# Read every fourth line in Python

Tags: python

I have a file where I am trying to read (and write to another file) every fourth line. The solution I'm using doesn't give the desired outcome.

**sample.txt**

`line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10`

**script.py**

```
from itertools import islice
with open('sample.txt') as fin, open('output.txt','w') as fout:
         fout.writelines(islice(fin,None,None,4))
```

Now the output file gives me line1, line5, line9 instead of line4, line8.

How would I go about altering this to get the desired outcome?

Comment: excellent use of `islice`

Comment: You will end up with a blank line added to your file  so you might want to catch cases where that will be a problem later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there. [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) comes with a `start` parameter. In your case, it's the second one, that you've set to `None`. Try this:

```
fout.writelines(islice(fin,3,None,4)) # line with index 3 is the fourth line
```

Comment: Ahh perfect. That was it. Looks like I was close. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
islice(fin,3,None,4) # start from 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by default list slicing (without `itertools`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('sample.txt') as fin, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
fout.write(''.join(fin.readlines()[3::4]))
```